# include an APK in Android.mk

Tags: android

I'm writing a Android.mk to make a APK-A. and APK-A would use other classes defined in APK-B. I wonder that how should I wrote the Android.mk to include APK-B. Which tag should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into the new [library projects feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject) in the [SDK Tools r6](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html), which were released coincidentally with the Android 2.2 SDK. Note that you can use the new tools for pre-2.2 projects as well.